# Android ExoPlayer Listener Infinite loop

Tags: android, loops, listener, infinite-loop, exoplayer

I want to use ExoPlayer with SurfaceView and SeekBar. buildTrackName function I took from ExoPlayer Demo. I want to use SeekBar for changing position of player and listView for displaying all of audio track of my video. When I'm use ExoPlayer functions to get player duration or get all audio tracks from video, these functions return -1 for getDuration() and 0 for getTrackCount(). I tried to put these functions in different parts of the code, but they work only in onPlayerStateChanged method of ExoPlayer.Listener. But! in this case, after all the functions, the program goes into an infinite loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private String videoPath = "myVideoPath";
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> trackList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

trackList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, audioList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

MediaCodecSelector mediaCodecSelector = MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT;

Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, "test");
ExtractorSampleSource extractorSampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
        uri, dataSource, new DefaultAllocator(64*1024), 256*64*1024,null);
MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(this,extractorSampleSource,mediaCodecSelector,MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(
        extractorSampleSource, mediaCodecSelector);

exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(2);

exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

exoPlayer.prepare(videoRenderer,audioRenderer);

exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

exoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY){
            seekBar.setMax((int)exoPlayer.getDuration());         
            int trackCount = exoPlayer.getTrackCount(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; i++) {
                trackList.add(buildTrackName(exoPlayer.getTrackFormat(1, i)));
            }
        } //infinite loop after this place
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }
});

}

///
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ExoPlayer 2 brigns supports seamless looping of videos with [LoopingMediaSource](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/LoopingMediaSource.html)